# React: npm command to create a new component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I want to create a new component by a command.

The command which I want to create will be the same output of the command in Angular 2: "ng generate component Test".

I have search on the internet and there is a reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-reactjs-component.

However, it doesn't work for me. The terminal shows errors:

```
PS C:\Users\anhtranv1\Desktop\react-app> npm install -g create-reactjs-component Test
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: Test@latest
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\anhtranv1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10- 
29T10_39_16_863Z-debug.log
```

Is there anyone can give me a command to create a component in react?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: "Because it's just a command, so please don't send me a link, please just paste the command here." Well, the command is *in the link* that you posted.

Comment: @str I did try the command but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: You did not try the commands from the link. Instead you merged the two in a single command which does not work.

Comment: I tried both and none of them works. The first command doesn't throw error but it doesn't create a new component. The 2nd throws another exception: "'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: The readme explicitly says *'the scripts are bash scripts and may not run on Windows machines. If that is the case, please use Git Bash'*. Judging by your command prompt, you're using PowerShell.

Comment: @JoeClay I was using Node.js command prompt. Do you mean that the command above must be run using Git Bash?

Comment: @anhtv13: Yes - the scripts contained in the package are written in Bash, not JavaScript. You must be using a Bash prompt like Git Bash or Cygwin to run them.

Comment: @JoeClay thank you very much. I created a new component successfully using Git Bash. Since you didn't post an answer, I cannot vote your suggestion as marked answer but anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

With `npm install -g create-reactjs-component` you install the npm package globally.

After you installed the package globally with the above command you can create a component with `create-reactjs-component YourComponentName`.

Please read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-reactjs-component) of the package, it's all described there.

Comment: After the 2nd command, I got an error: 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
How to run this command? I use Node.js command prompt.

Comment: This error is related to the comment from @JoeClay above. But as i see you now solved your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out generate-react-cli. Really straightforward and easy to use.

install: `npm install -g generate-react-cli`

run: `generate-react component Box`

That's it

repo: https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli

Comment: ++ because this includes storybook and typescript, while what shows up on google does not

Answer (score 0):

What are you telling him here :

> npm install -g create-reactjs-component Test

Is to install **Globally** *`create-reactjs-component`* **AND** *`Test`*, however there is no `Test` defined in [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/),

- [Install your CLI tool dep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-reactjs-component#install)
- [Create your component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-reactjs-component#example)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`react-component`](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates/docs/main/templates/react-component) template from [templates](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates).

**Supports:** typescript, storybook, multiple css languages, and more!

Want more? Need it to fit your code better? use the `copy` command and change it to how you want

Feedback or contributions are welcome!